# Display database table in html through javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am trying to display a database table in html. I have the following php code that will get the table and return in an html table format and it has no errors:
    function viewPlane()
    {

```
if(!$this->DBLogin())
    {
        $this->HandleError("Database login failed!");
        return false;
    }

$qry = "select * from airplane";
$result = mysql_query($qry,$this->connection); 

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Registration Number</th>
<th>Model Number</th>
</tr>";

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Registration_Number'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Model_Number'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";

}
```

In the html file, I have the following javascript code that calls the php function and Supposedly adds it to the div:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">  
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu_active").click(function(){  
       $("#table").after('<?php $test->viewplane(); ?>')  
    });
});  
</script>
```

The code:

```
<?php $test->viewplane(); ?>
```

works when put among the html, so why is not working ?

Comment: What does the generated JavaScript look like? What does the JavaScript error console say?

Comment: there is no error, it just doesn't display anything. If I replace the code: <?php $test->viewplane(); ?> with a normal string it works.

Answer (score 0):

There could be other problems (it helps if you look at your generated JavaScript and your JavaScript error console), but at the very least, this:

```
<table border='1'>
<tr>
```

… contains `'` characters which cannot be used unescaped in a JavaScript string literal delimited with `'` characters and new line characters which cannot be used unescaped in any JavaScript string literal.

You need to add some `\`s, or possibly switch to using the `json_encode` function instead of building your string literal by hand.

Comment: you are right about the ' character , but it is not the problem. Even after removing it or editing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not correct to write `$("#table").after('<?php $test->viewplane(); ?>')`
the javascript is executed in the browser, so during the js executing process, it just treat `<?php $test->viewplane(); ?>` as a simple string.

I mean when you click `"#menu_active"`, the after method is invoked, but the after method is **NOT** responsible to send a http request to the server side to get the content.

To achieve what you want, you might need a Ajax call when the `"#menu_active"` is clicked.
Something like `$("selector here").load` method will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a table with an id of table (`#table)` in your code:

```
$("#table").after('<?php $test->viewplane(); ?>')
```

If a selector doesn't work in jQuery, there's no error it just doesn't do anything.

Also, this is probably irrelevant here, but sometimes [PHP doesn't evaluate variables contained inside of single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php). Not sure if that matters inside of HTML.